# Screens turn black after plugging in external screen (vga and hdmi)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vga

I have a dell xp13 with the latest Kubuntu. I used to work fine when I plugged in my external screen or a projector (I give presentations all the time).

Now all of a sudden (I think I might have been pressing a key when I plugged in the screen) both of the screens turn black when I plug in the thunderbolt with vga or hdmi and I see my mouse in on the left side of the external screen and can move it up and down (no other movement).

I tried pressing Fn-F8, but to no avail. Is there anything I can check (error log?) or do? I normally use kscreen to configure the displays, but since the screen is black I can't do anything after plugging it in.

update--

I noticed the screen cable doesn't even need to be plugged in. As soon as I plug in the thunderbolt adapter, the laptop screen goes black. I unplug it and the laptop screen comes back.

update2-- all of a sudden it worked. Then it broke again, I was just working with INScore, and browsing the web. My cursor first dissapeared. I rebooted and the screen problem was back. Rebootet about 5 times already and still persists. As soon as I plug the thunderbolt in, screen fades to black...

Any log file I could check?

Thanks for any help!

--update:

I see this in /var/log/Xorg.0.log. I think this looks normal no? Or am I missing something...

```
[ 16611.424] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1024x768@60.0 on DP1 using pipe 0, position (3200, 720), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 16617.756] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 3200x1800@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
```

--update2
I just logged in as system admin to kde and it seemed to work. However, logging in as my regular user, same problem. Could it be a settings file specific to the user somewhere?

Also found this in the log file:

```
5.688] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
5.688] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
```

Comment: Mmmm... with some fiddleing in kscreen the vga option works. But if I plug in the thunderbolt with hdmi it seems to crash plasma (how can I check this?). It worked fine before.

Comment: Ok, all of a sudden my mouse pointer disappeared and since then the problem is back. This is kind of a disaster. I have to give an important talk on Monday. Have rebooted 5 times already and always the desktop crashes, black screens

Comment: have you rebooted Ubuntu, after you plugged in the extern Display (via hdmi) ?

Comment: yes I have rebooted multiple times. It works well, but as soon as I login, it crashes. I have created a new user and it works for the new user. I've tried enabling the compositor on startup (it was disable because of a bug with the XPS13), openGL2.0 gives me flickering, but maybe opernGL3 works better... at least in connecting the thunderbolt... now trying the screen... The second user does give me an alternative to survive my presentation (although slightly a hassle)

Comment: Is there a 'Screen Display' manager in KDE.  When I was having trouble (in Unity) displaying on an external monitor I changed the settings here.

Comment: @dorien - is xserver xorg installed ? when I am not wrong, there was something as package too for multiple displays somewhere - rather I cannot recall the name of this package.

Comment: I have xserver xorg installed. I couldn't immediately find a package about multiple displays. I have been wondering if it's something in the .plasma folder. Could I just delete that?

Comment: I have the same problem with an Acer Aspire laptop.  Just switching the compositor doesn't solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compositor seems to have an influence on this (at least for me). I've made sure the compositor was enabled on startup. And switched from openGL3.1 to 2.0. This made a difference but caused some screen flickering. XRender seemed to works lightly better. Sometimes it does still happen but a reboot seems to fix it when that setting is set.

I also created a new user and it worked fine with the new user.

--update: final solution: 
After deleting the kscreen folder in .config, and all files starting with plasma, things worked out for me. There is an official bug report about this [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359602).

Comment: Still keeps happening though randomnly. THen I reboot a few times, play with the compositor settings... also there is a kwin crash each time I  unplug the thunderbolt

Comment: It came back and it stuck. The screen almost nicely fades to black so I'm really wondering if it's just a setting. Works fine for another user.

Comment: While I cant help on your question, you said it works fine for another user which to me says that it must be your settings causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense :) the question is which setting... Kscreen doesn't have many settings. Is the xrandr info stored somewhere?

Comment: On my system, Kubuntu 16.10, the folder was here: ~/.local/share/kscreen